# How can I add paragraphs to a translated node?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, paragraphs

I have a problem with the Paragraphs module and translation. I'm using Drupal 8.7.7 and Paragraphs 8.x-1.9.

When I add a translation to a node with a paragraphs field (unlimited), I can only translate existing fields in this paragraph, but I cannot add new values on the translation node.

[image]
[image]

I followed the instructions given in the docs on  https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/paragraphs/multilingual-paragraphs-configuration and in fact, if I didn't I wouldn't have been able to even see the fields in the translation edit form.

I have no idea, how to set this up correctly.

I installed the [Paragraphs Asymmetric Translation Widgets](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_asymmetric_translation_widgets) module which somehow says, it deals with it, but it does not. I used the Widget 'Paragraphs Classic Asymmetric' in the form display, but to no avail.

I'm really desperate now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no solution out of the box yet.

There are two features that are not realised at the same time.

- The *Paragraphs EXPERIMENTAL* widget by the [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module provides for a drag & drop mode mode
- The *Paragraphs Classic Asymmetric* widget from [Paragraphs Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_features) module provides the functionality of asymmetric translation

There is no *Paragraphs EXPERIMENTAL Asymmetric* widget

I decided to drop the Drag & Drop feature in favor of the asymmetric translation feature.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember this right this is by design (or maybe more a technical necessity). And you can only circumvent this by having multi-value fields inside a paragraph type. Like a node reference field for example. This then can have a different number of items per language and even in a different order.

You could also add a new untranslatable "Visibility" field to each paragraph type, like [Paragraphs Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_collection) is offering it, see [2846682#comment-11887724](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_collection/issues/2846682#comment-11887724) for example. Then you add different paragraphs in the original language but set them to be displayed only in selected languages.

And regarding [Paragraphs Asymmetric Translation Widgets](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_asymmetric_translation_widgets) you may file a bug report in [its issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/paragraphs_asymmetric_translation_widgets).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by making the paragraph field on the node **translatable**.

This can be done by going to manage fields of the content type and editing the paragraph field and then tick the checkbox **"Users may translate this field**"

More information on this particular point can be found on the  [Paragraphs Asymmetric Translation Widgets](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs_asymmetric_translation_widgets) module page.